# How to make <span> object inside of paragraph in CSS send you to a link when clicked?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a paragraph object such as the following:

```HTML
<p>This is an example of a <span class="paragraph-link-example"> paragraph </span> </p>
```

<strike>(Stackoverflow isn't showing the HTML tags, so here is an image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLxD2.png</strike>

How do I make the `.paragraph-link-example` class open a new link (preset by me) when clicked?

Comment: You need to wrap it in an <a href>

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to replace the `<span>` by a `<a href="{your link}"> Your text</a>`.

Comment: You can add a class to style it and target=”_blank” to open it in a new browser window

Answer (score 1):

1. You can either replace `<span>` with `<a href="https://google.com">GOOGLE</a>` tag and style that.
2. OR place `<a href="https://google.com">` tag within the `<span>` like `<span> <a href="https://google.com"> </span>`
3. OR add script in js like this:

```js
const paragraphLink = document.querySelector("https://google.com");

paragraphLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location = "https://google.com";
});
```